# how to click on a link present in a grid that comes after a window pop up using selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I need help in JavaScript for Selenium Web Driver.

I want to click on a link present in a grid and that grid will open on clicking a button.The link is in a grid.
So my question is: how to click on that link by using any syntax or command in web driver?
There is only xpath given for that link and still the problem is not getting solved.
the command i am using is

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*@id='ctl00$PageBody$ucAgList$grd']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span")).click();
```

and also i need to click on a button with 
href=javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("ctl00$PageBody$Button1", "", true, "", "", false, true)).
but by using the id it is not working and tell me how to use this href.

the complete html code for this is

but it is not working.

Comment: Well how does it not work?

Comment: Not very much information to go with, but try locating by linktext? http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByLinkText.html

Comment: its not working because the link is located in a grid.

Comment: actually the id given is "page_button1" and it is not getting clicked as the button is present in a grid

Answer (score 0):

First:You are trying the xpath which has an ID so try to click the Button using ID

```
driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00$PageBody$ucAgList$grd"))
```

Still if you not found the solution, Post the complete details of the Html.

Comment: still i am not getting the solution..by id it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicit wait for it.

```
WebDriverWait webwait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
webwait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*@id='ctl00$PageBody$ucAgList$grd']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span"))).click();
```

It  should wait for 10 second max and click the field.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything else you've done is correct, there is a typo in the xpath you've provided above, you're missing the opening square bracket in the first part, it should be:

> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//***[**@id='ctl00$PageBody$ucAgList$grd']/tbody/tr/td[4]/span")).click();